# How do I comment lines in fstab using sed?

Tags: linux, sed, fstab

I want to comment certain lines in `fstab` using `sed` command. The following are the lines I need to comment:

```
172.0.0.1:/export/project/common /nfs/share nfs4 rw,bg,hard,nointr,rsize=131072,wsize=131072,proto=tcp
172.0.0.1:/export/project/share1 /nfs/shares1 nfs4 rw,bg,hard,nointr,rsize=131072,wsize=131072,proto=tcp
```

I tried using this command but it didn't work:

```
sed -i '/172.0.0.1:/export/project/common /nfs/share nfs4 rw,bg,hard,nointr,rsize=131072,wsize=131072,proto=tcp /s/^/#/' /etc/fstab_test
sed -i '/172.0.0.1:/export/project/share1 /nfs/shares1 nfs4 rw,bg,hard,nointr,rsize=131072,wsize=131072,proto=tcp /s/^/#/' /etc/fstab_test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

`sed -e '/[/]/common s/^/#/' /etc/fstab`
`sed -e '/[/]/share1 s/^/#/' /etc/fstab`

Specifying this `/[/]common/` will select only lines that contain /common.

If this works then replace `-e` with `-i` for executing the changing into the file.

You can do this with `awk`

```
awk '/[/]common/{$0="#"$0} 1' /etc/fstab >/etc/fstab.tmp && mv /etc/fstab.tmp /etc/fstab 
awk '/[/]share1/{$0="#"$0} 1' /etc/fstab >/etc/fstab.tmp && mv /etc/fstab.tmp /etc/fstab
```

Specifying this `/[/]common/ {$0="#"$0}` will chose those lines containing /common and place a # at the beginning of the line.

Comment: awk work like charm, but i have smalll query. when run awk command. it also comment all other shares which has common in them, is there a way to only comment common of specific project /project1/common

Comment: you can select something which is unique on those line of `fstab` file.

Comment: if the full paths (either NFS remote or local mount point) are the only unique things on a line, then you'll have to use one of them.  and remember to escape **all** `/`s as `\/`.